# calling a javascript pop up on same page which should have dynamic values in input text

Tags: javascript

I want to open a pop up on clicking different hyperlinks and want to call the id of clicked hyperlink in the input field of pop up. And also when I submit the pop up it should redirect me to different jsp page.

I am trying with the below code:

```
    <c:forEach var="legList" items="${legList}">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" class="legid" name="legid" 
    id=${legList.ledgerId}
    value=${legList.ledgerId}> 
    **<a href="#" id="mylink" 
    onclick="display(document.getElementById(${legList.ledgerId}).value); 
    return false">${legList.ledgerName}</a>**
    </td>
    <td>
    <c:forEach var="periodList" items="${periodList}">
    <c:forEach var="attriList" items="${attriList}">
    <c:if test="${periodList.period eq attriList.periodName && 
    legList.ledgerName eq attriList.legName}">
    </td>
    <td>${attriList.AP}</td>
    <td>${attriList.OKL}</td>
    <td>${attriList.LM}</td>
    <td>${attriList.GL}</td>
    </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Above code will show the table somehow below like this(content will be same but style is different in below image):

[In this image I want to open a pop up by clicking on hyperlinks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNHDE.png)

[here is pop up which will open after clicking on hyperlinks in which I want to call ledgerId and ledger name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idPA0.png)

Basically I want to call a simple javascript pop up where I will call dynamic values and will redirect that pop up to jsp after submitting the form.**whole code may be ignored and one can concentrate on anchor tag from where I want to call a javacsript pop up on click**.

Please help me with the code.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the full jstl code ?, i dont see your foreach end tag.

Comment: I have edited the code , u can see now and in code important part is I want to know call javascript pop up from anchor tag(logic part is not required that how data is being dispalyed on page)